# Using ifelse conditional statements

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

So I have a large data set with and I would like to check a number of columns and rows with a key. There are 20 questions (columns) and 76 rows so that would be quite hectic to do by hand.

```
Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  Q6  Q7  Q8  Q9  Q10 Q11 Q12 Q13 Q14 Q15 Q16 Q17 Q18 Q19 Q20
        B   B   C   C   B   B   D   C   A   C   C   A   D   B   B   A   B   D
B   C   C   C   C   C   B   D   B   C   A   C   C   A   C   B   A   C   B   D
B   C   B   A   C   B   B   C   D   C   C   C   C   C   D   B   C   A   B   A
B   C   B   C   C   C   B   D   D   C   C   A   C   A   D   B   D   A   C   D
B   C   C   B   C   C   B   D   C   C   C   A   C   B   C   B   A   B   B   D
C   C   D   C   C   C   B   B   D   C   C   A   C   C   D   B   C   A   B   D
B   C   C   D   C   C   B   B   B   C   A   A   C   A   D   B   A   B   B   D
B   C   B   B   C   C   B   D   C   C   C   C   C   A   D   B   A   A   B   D
B   C   B   B   C   C   B   D   C   C   C   A   C   A   D   B   A   D   B   A
B   C   B   B   C   C   B   B   D   C   C   C   C   A   D   B   B   A   B   D
B   A   B   D   A   C   B   B   D   C   C   C   C   A   D   B   A   B   C   D
B   C   C   C   C   C   B   D   D   C   C   A   C   B   C   B   D   A   B   D
B   C   B   B   C   C   B   D   D   C   C   C   C   C   D   B   B   A   B   A
B   C   B   D   C   C   B   B   B   C   C   A   C   B   D   B   A   C   D   D
B   C   B   B   C   C   B   D   D   C   C   A   C   B   D   B   A   B   B   D
B   C   B   B   C   C   B   B   D   C   C   C   C   B   C   B   D   A   B   D
A   C   C   B   C   C   B   D   D   C   C   C   C   B   D   B   C   A   B   D
B   C   A   B   C   A   B   B   D   C   C   C   B   B   C   D   A   B   B   D
```

```
KEY=c('B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'D');
```

I want to run a if and else statement, and maybe a for loop to assign a 1 to each column that has the correct letter corresponding to the key and 0 to ones that don't correctly correspond to the key. This is what I have so far, but I am unable to get it to go through the rows and columns correctly to assign the correct value.

```
 for(i in 1:nrow(scores)){
  if(scores[i,6:25] == KEY){
    scores[i,6] <- 1
  }
  else{
    scores[i, length(scores)] <- 0
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really quick if we convert to a matrix and check equality with `==`. We have to do a transpose because R treats matrices in column-major order:

```
scores = t(t(dd) == KEY)
mode(scores) = "integer"
scores
#      Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Q6 Q7 Q8 Q9 Q10 Q11 Q12 Q13 Q14 Q15 Q16 Q17 Q18 Q19 Q20
#  [1,] NA NA  1  0  1  1  1  0  1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
#  [2,]  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1
#  [3,]  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0
#  [4,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1
#  [5,]  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1
#  [6,]  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   1
#  [7,]  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1
#  [8,]  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
#  [9,]  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0
# [10,]  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
# ...
```

The result is a matrix, you may want to run `as.data.frame()` on it to get it back to data frame.

---

Using this data:

```
dd = read.table(text = 'Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  Q6  Q7  Q8  Q9  Q10 Q11 Q12 Q13 Q14 Q15 Q16 Q17 Q18 Q19 Q20
NA  NA      B   B   C   C   B   B   D   C   A   C   C   A   D   B   B   A   B   D
B   C   C   C   C   C   B   D   B   C   A   C   C   A   C   B   A   C   B   D
B   C   B   A   C   B   B   C   D   C   C   C   C   C   D   B   C   A   B   A
B   C   B   C   C   C   B   D   D   C   C   A   C   A   D   B   D   A   C   D
B   C   C   B   C   C   B   D   C   C   C   A   C   B   C   B   A   B   B   D
C   C   D   C   C   C   B   B   D   C   C   A   C   C   D   B   C   A   B   D
B   C   C   D   C   C   B   B   B   C   A   A   C   A   D   B   A   B   B   D
B   C   B   B   C   C   B   D   C   C   C   C   C   A   D   B   A   A   B   D
B   C   B   B   C   C   B   D   C   C   C   A   C   A   D   B   A   D   B   A
B   C   B   B   C   C   B   B   D   C   C   C   C   A   D   B   B   A   B   D', header = TRUE)

KEY=c('B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'D')
```